# arbor.js: How do you implement a tooltip on hover funcitonality?

Tags: javascript, jquery, arbor.js

Is there a built in functionality for Arbor? or I have to implement it myself?

Comment: No such a way in arbor.js you have to manage it by your self

Comment: That makes it a little bit difficult. Do you know a way where I can capture the hover event of a node?